# Implementing PyMyType_Check methods with Python C API?

Tags: c++, python, c, python-c-api

All the Python-provided types have a check method (i.e., `PyList_Check`) that allows you to check if an arbitrary `PyObject*` is actually a specific type.

How can I implement this for my own types?  I haven't found anything good online for this, though it seems like a pretty normal thing to want to do.

Also, maybe I'm just terrible at looking through large source trees, but I cannot for the life of me find the implementation of `PyList_Check` or any of it's companions in the Python (2.5) source.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyMemberDef (yes, I know that is 2.6.5 docs, but I'd bee surprised if essential structures changed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [they're macros](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Include/listobject.h?revision=59564&view=markup) that use deep magic. Save yourself a bit of headache and use [`PyObject_IsInstance()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsInstance) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to implement your own macro, you could try...

```
#define PyMyType_Check(op) \
    PyObject_TypeCheck(op, &PyMyType_Type)
```